# Problems regarding Overloading the input operator >> for reading text file

Tags: c++, overloading, istream

I have a `Point2D` class and i am trying to overload the input operator >>

```
class Point2D
{
 public:
           Point2D(int,int);
           int getX();
           int getY();

           void setX(int);
           void setY(int);

           double getScalarValue();

          bool operator < ( const Point2D& x2) const
          {
            return x < x2.x;
          }

              friend istream& operator >> (istream&,Point2D);


 protected:

             int x;
             int y;
             double distFrOrigin;
             void setDistFrOrigin();


};
```

Outside my main function

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include "Line2D.h"
    #include "MyTemplates.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <set>

    using namespace std;

    istream operator >> (istream& is , Point2D p2d)
    {
        string p;
        getline(is,p,'\n');
       int position = p.find(", ");

        string k = p.substr(0,position);

       if ( k == "Point2D")
       {
         string x = p.substr(10,1);
         int x_coordinate = atoi(x.c_str()); // atoi(x.c_str()) convert string x to int
         p2d.setX(x_coordinate);

       }

       return is;
    }
```

In my int main()

```
    int main()
{

   fstream afile;
   string p;
   afile.open("Messy.txt",ios::in);

   if (!afile)
   {
     cout<<"File could not be opened for reading";
     exit(-1);
   }

   Point2D abc;

   afile>>abc;

   set<Point2D> P2D;
   P2D.insert(abc);

   set<Point2D>::iterator p2 = P2D.begin();

   while ( p2 != P2D.end() )
   { 
     cout<<p2->getX();
     p2++;
   }

}
```

I dont understand why am i getting an error:

> c++ forbids declaration of istream with no type

I have already included iostream , fstream , using namespace std , i cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: You need to return `std::istream` (it can't be copied, i.e., returning by value doesn't work) by reference and pass your argument by reference (otherwise you'd modify a local object). In your declaration (in the class) you should use `std::istream` instead of `istream`.

Comment: sorry i am new to c++ , what do you mean?

Comment: `istream` is in the `std` namespace, so you need `friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, Point2D&);` Don't use `using namespace std;`, it is bad anyway, and is leading to some confusion in your code.

Comment: what do i need to include std:: when i already have "using namespace std"

Comment: You are probably not `using namespace std` where you need it (don't do it anywhere to be safe), plus you may or may not be including a required header.

Comment: i have included it and it still doesnt work

Comment: Follow the advice given. If it still doesn't work, post some minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have added minimal code which reproduces the error

Comment: OK, looking at your code, I would repeat my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

1. This is the reason for your error message. You don't `#include <iostream>` in `Point2D.h`/`Line2D.h`.

   As others already suggested, use `std::istream` instead of just `istream`.
2. The correct `operator>>()` should be

   ```
   std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Point2D &p2d);
   ```

   Note the `std::istream&` *and* the `Point2D&`. `Point2D&` is important, because otherwise you modify a local copy and the given parameter remains unchanged.
3. Your input operator is fragile. It is vulnerable to having more or less whitespace. You also allow exactly *one* digit for `x_coordinate`. Additionally, you skip one character beyond `Point2D,`. A better approach could be to separate the parts with just whitespace and let the iostream library handle the parsing. E.g.

   ```
   Point2D 15 28
   ```

   could be read by

   ```
   string tag;
   is >> tag;
   if (tag == "Point2D")
       is >> p2d.x >> p2d.y;

   return is,
   ```

Comment: just wondering why must i repeat #include <iostream> in my Point2D header file when i have already included it in my main file

Comment: You don't need to, of course. But as you can see, relying on the inclusion somewhere else *and* `using namespace` gives you the error message. If you insist on including `iostream` before `Line2D`, you must also say using namespace *before* including `Line2D`. Therefore it is best to do the necessary prerequisites in the relevant header file and not somewhere else. Thus the recommendation: do the include in `Line2D` and use `std::istream` instead of `using namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that pops out (as Dietmar Kühl mentioned) is that you aren't returning a reference of istream. Try changing this method header

```
istream operator >> (istream& is , Point2D p2d)
```

to this:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& is , Point2D p2d)
```

As a rule of thumb returning a reference to an object that you haven't made a copy constructor for is usually a good idea. Returning a reference means that you are returning the address that the object is located. To correctly return by value, there needs to be a copy made of the object being returned.